# SQL in a c# Code Where clause issues

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an array of integers say array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

The array of integers is created from an array of strings using this command

```
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse);
```

I am trying to extract some data from the database db1

```
sql = $"SELECT col1, col2 from dbo.databas1 WHERE col1 in array";
```

I am fairly certain that my SQL code is wrong towards the end in the where clause. Can anyone tell me how implement the where clause in the SQL code?

Col1 is bigint (if it is of any help)

Comment: `sql = string.Format("SELECT col1, col2 from dbo.databas1 WHERE col1 in {0}", array.join(','))`

Comment: Don't build SQL through string concatenation. That being said, parameterizing `IN` is hard, and requires ... string concatenation. See [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause).

Comment: @believeme bad idea.

Comment: @CodeCaster - arguably not a huge issue if there is a validation that all parameters are indeed integers - however you never know when someone will change them to string and you can have sql injection problem :)

Comment: @DanielA.White you're right but this just answers OP's question in his own way

Comment: @CodeCaster Or you can use a User Defined Table Type

Comment: @believeme  My array doesn't have a .join method?

Comment: @Morpheus sure it does, it depends how your code is written